# How to copy content from html into excel with desired format (that contains all rows and certain columns)

Tags: python, html, excel, beautifulsoup

I tag this question with both excel and python is because I want to explore the possibilities of using either approach (by doing simple copy content from the website and paste it to excel with the right format, or use any python library to extract the content and covert to a dataframe).

I need to copy and paste the below table into excel from https://ndcpartnership.org/climate-tools/ndcs .However,  The format I need to have in excel file contains row (all records) and 3 columns include "Country", "Latest Submission" and "Latest submission date" like what I see from the table below.

However, when I select all ,copy the entire table and paste over to excel cell, I only get certain rows of records (all records shown in one column). I have tried to inspect the URL and attempted to use bs4 but I do not see all the info (3 columns I mentioned above) I need from the html structure, so I did not have any code posted in this question. Given this is a one time effort, I want to figure out a way to paste the content in a desired format into excel.

Any suggestions and advice are highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "correct format"?

Comment: You can download the data and there's even an API

Comment: Hi @BigBen, "correct format" means row and columns like first column for country and so on

Comment: ... use the API.

Comment: @tobiv, I tried to click on the download the data button but whatever being downloaded is not the same as what I see from that table.

Comment: @BigBen, I couldn't find the api, do you mind to walk me through one step further?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: this page use JavaScript to read data - and it really use some (private) API for this. If you use `DevTools` (tab `Network`, filter `XHR`) in `Chrome`/`Firefox` to see all requests send from browser to server then you can see url `https://www.climatewatchdata.org/api/v1/locations/countries` and maybe it send expected data as JSON

Comment: in url `https://www.climatewatchdata.org/api/v1/ndcs?indicators=ndce_ghg,%20submission,%20submission_date&filter=map&source[]=CAIT&source[]=WB&source[]=NDC%20Explorer` I see percentage from last column `Share of Global GHG ...`

Comment: @furas, there is no code. Basically what I tried to do is just to copy and paste the content into excel. However, when I copy and paste over to excel, whatever I am seeing looks very weird and it does not have all the info I need. I tried to get at least a column with all countries and "last submission" as well as "submission date" columns.  the URL https://www.climatewatchdata.org/api/v1/locations/countries seems to have countries info. Let me see if I can try to find the other two columns info. Thanks

Comment: if you don't have any code then first you have to learn python and some modules for scraping - `requests`/`urlli`, `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) - and later try to write some code and when you get error then ask question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @furas, I know how to code in python and using bs4. But when I inspect the url, I cannot find all the info I need from the html hierarchy structure. I decided to do a copy and paste to excel since this’s a one time job that may not worth the effort of automation. But copy and paste just doesn’t paste all the info I need at once. Since I want to explore possibilities of using different approach/tool for a solution, I specified precisely the reason why I tag this post with both excel and python in the first statement of my question.

Comment: if you  know how to code in python and using bs4 then you should say it in question (or even show some code in question). Problem is this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `BS4` can't run JavaScript - you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you have to search requests which send data from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the table from the above website is not a table but a dynamic web element that automatically updates and refreshes.

Thus, the most efficient solution for this one time task would implementing a semi-automation solution (mixed with excel and python) as below given there is no way to copy and paste all the desired rows and columns into excel at once or using bs4 to web scraping the desired 3 columns:

Step 1: Copy and paste 10 records/rows each time into excel, as pasting more than 11 records do not work in this case, then save the excel file. Be noted, after paste over, each record would transpose from one row and five columns into 5 rows and 1 columns.

Step 2: Use below codes to get the dataframe.

```
ndc = pd.read_excel("ndc.xsx")

ndc_cont = [] # get a list of country

for i in range(0,984,5): 
    cont = ndc.loc[i,'column'] 
    ndc_cont.append(cont)

print(len(ndc_cont))

ndc_value = [] # get submission value

for i in range(2,984,5): 
    sub_val = ndc.loc[i,'column'] 
    ndc_value.append(sub_val) 
print(len(ndc_value))

ndc_date = [] # get submission date

for i in range(3,984,5): 
    dt = ndc.loc[i,'column'] ndc_date.append(dt)

print(len(ndc_date))

df_final = pd.DataFrame( {'country': ndc_cont, 'value': ndc_value, 
'year':ndc_date })
```